# Fill UIStackView by Ratio?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have a horizontal `UIStackView` with 2 views within it.  I'd like to have the left view take up ~70% of the screen, and the right view take up the remaining 30%.  I know that I can set the `UIStackView` alignment to Fill and the distribution to Fill and that will allow me to have more control over my subview sizes.  What I can't figure out is how to set the layout constraints/widths/etc. on the subviews so that the the 70/30 ratio is correct, particularly when the device is rotated?

Can anyone explain how to set the constraints on my subviews so that the 70/30 ratio is maintained across device rotations?

Comment: Create an equal width constraint between the two views and set the multiplier to 70/30

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by creating an equal width constraint for the two views.  Then, set the multiplier to that constraint to 0.7.

Comment: i have three views vertically. this is possible in multiplier.

Comment: In that case, put the three views into a container view, lay them out vertically as you want, and set the equal width constraint and multiplier on the container view.